# Incomplete filedownloads with python

Tags: python, urllib2

I have the following python code:

```
import urllib2
DIR = '/home/aaron/Desktop/aaron-file/media/'
LOC = DIR+'/'+bounty.title+'.mp3'

u = urllib2.urlopen(url, 'rb')
localFile = open(LOC, 'wb')
localFile.write(u.read())
localFile.close()
u.close()
```

It only creates small (roughly 60kb files), the files operate correctly accept for the sudden stop. When I download from firefox (copy and paste the same url) I get full sized files (roughly 2mb).

I am running 32bit ubuntu.

UPDATE:
I believe it may be a problem with the http content-length being inaccurate. How then would I ignore/set different length.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a sample URL

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the server, from which you are downloading rejects urllib2 default user agent. Consider constructing a custom opener with a fake user agent header, like this:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
```

and use `opener()` instead of `urllib2.urlopen()`